# ParseObject Subclass to simple ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a simple list view from a list of `ParseObjects`. The issue is the `toString` method doesn't seem to be overriding the super class, so I'm just getting the class name displayed **(e.g., com.parse.ParseObject@416161e8)** in the list view. I've created this exact setup before without using a `ParseObject` and it works how I'd expect. Am I just missing something simple?

My class that extends `ParseObject`

```
@ParseClassName("Foo")
public class Foo extends ParseObject {
    public String getName(){
        return getString("name");
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        put("name", name);
    }

    public String getType(){
        return getString("type");
    }
    public void setType(String type){
        put("type", type);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

My code that sets the listview adapter.

```
    ParseQuery<Foo> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Foo.class);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Foo>() {
        public void done(List<Foo> foos, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Foo>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foos));
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I missed in the docs about registering the sub class.

Place `ParseObject.registerSubclass(YOURSUBLCASS.class);` before `Parse.initialize(...)`